# Android: Wait for button click

Tags: java, android, user-interface, asynchronous, jsch

I have to implement a return method of a class. So the structure is as simple as

```
public boolean yesNo(String message){
    //return something
}
```

The problem here is that there is an EditText object and a Button and I want return a boolean depending on the answer entered by the User in the EditText. So naturally I have to wait for the user to write and click the Button when he finishes. I already tried setting up an onClicklistener inside the method but then I would not be able to pass anything to the outer method.

I know that in android everything is asynchronous so I you are not supposed to wait for the user to do something but in this case I have no other idea. Also FYI the method that I'm implementing is of the UserInfo class of the Jsch library. From what i understood this UserInfo is designed for user interaction so I figured it would somehow manage "prompt" the user by calling the yesNo method and then "wait" for the user to react. Any ideas? Also I would be happy if anyone would explain to me if there is some error in my logic. Im not quite confident in using AsynTask or runnables but I think its got something to do with this.

[The only available documentation of UserInfo class](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: code so far:

```
public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

    public Button goButton = (Button) MainActivity.contentView.findViewById(R.id.startSSH);

    public EditText editText = (EditText) MainActivity.contentView.findViewById(R.id.commandSSH);

    public boolean yesNo = false;

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String answer = editText.getText().toString();
                if(answer.equals("yes")){yesNo = true;}
                else {yesNo = false;}
            }
        });
        return yesNo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried setting up an onClicklistener inside the method but
>   then i would not be able to pass anything to the outer method.

What do you want to pass to the outer method? You can create class variables to make it available inside the whole class.

The promptYesNo method:

```
public void promptYesNo(String s) {
 if(s.equals("Yes") //do something
 else if(s.equals("No") //do something
}
```

Change your code this way:

```
public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

    public Button goButton = (Button) MainActivity.contentView.findViewById(R.id.startSSH);

    public EditText editText = (EditText) MainActivity.contentView.findViewById(R.id.commandSSH);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (prompt) {
                promptYesNo(editText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What i tried was to set a String thats public in the Class inside the OnClickListeners onClick method but then it tells me that the String has to be final. But when its final i cant change it. Thats kind of why it did not work with the onClicklistener. But maybe i missed something. Any idea?

Comment: Ahh my bad. I declared the String inside the YesNo method.

Comment: i added the code so far. So what does this do to the lifecycle? Does this return the yesNo boolean only after the button was clicked?  Because if its returned either way its no use to me

Comment: The method promptYesNo will not be called every time goButton is clicked, but only when someCondition is true

Comment: I see where you are getting at but as i commented  in @Gex answer Im not the one who calls the prompt. its done by another object. So i think this would not do what i need

Comment: One thing you can do is to make someCondition a class variable and set it to true or false depending on who is calling prompt.

Comment: To make onClick to be called you need to click the button

Comment: Okay so how would i determine who called the prompt?

Comment: You need to determine it depending on the parameters if any, if there is no parameter just make someCondition true if prompt is called

Comment: So when the button is clicked( assuming the condition is true) you can do what you want

Comment: I have changed someCondition to prompt to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Put an `OnClickListener` on the `Button` when the screen is initialized, for example at `onCreate` lifecycle method. At the listener's `onClick` method you can call the `yesNo` method with the `EditText` content.

Try this way at the screen's `onCreate` method:

```
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        yesNo(mEditText.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But the way it is supposed to work is that the yesNo method is called on ther UserInfo Object from somwhere else ie not every time the button is pressed.